# Evaluate Your Site -- A Check for Quality

Tags: discussion, site-information, quality-evaluation

One of the most important aspects of being a Stack Exchange site is quality. Yes, there are lots of metrics that one can use to "measure" a site, but we don't really care about those as much as we care about a site providing expert answers to good questions. To that end, we're introducing a self-evaluation to our sites!

This process is currently still in the midst of being put together, but you all are going to be a lucky early-adopter! Here's a rough guide:

- Below, you'll find ten questions randomly selected from your site.
- For each question, search the internet for the question as if you were the asker!
- If our answer is good (complete, well-written, answers the question, found in search results, etc) then **vote it up**!
- If our answer is bad (incomplete, poorly-written, off-topic, unfindable, etc) then **vote it down**!

Comment with anything you feel is worth noting, or to explain your voting choice. We have a rough guide to better/par/worse [right here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQxi7.png). If your result is par, make a choice to vote up or down based on your instincts!

Ultimately, remember that our goal is to make the internet a better place. If you find yourself torn between the options, or if you can't decide, ask yourself: does this question and/or answer make the internet better? That should help you decide.

**This eval will close on March 21st! Get your answers in by then!**

Comment: Example of another site that did this: [Judaism self-evaluation](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/836/site-self-evaluation-how-are-you-doing).

Comment: Examples of `better` questions: [one](http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/11339/auto-pay-credit-card-from-checking-account-bad-idea) and [two](http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/12258/why-is-a-stock-that-pays-a-dividend-preferrable-to-one-that-doesnt).

Comment: Examples of `worse` questions: [one](http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/12311/calculating-the-cost-of-waiting-longer-for-money) and [two](http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/12361/definitions-of-leverage-and-of-leverage-factor).

Comment: Thank you for your help, everyone!

Comment: I think we could use more meta participation .. but the question is "how?"

Comment: The age-old question. :( If I had the magic wand or the silver bullet, I'd tell you. But I don't, so I can't.

Answer (score 2):

[Will "rate shopping" affect my credit score?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/13352/will-rate-shopping-affect-my-credit-score)

Better than, worse than, or similar to other sites out there?

Answer (score 1):

[Why can't I short a particular stock?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/13397/why-cant-i-short-a-particular-stock)

Better than, worse than, or similar to other sites out there?

Answer (score 1):

[What is the difference between fixed-income duration and equity duration?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/13406/what-is-the-difference-between-fixed-income-duration-and-equity-duration)

Better than, worse than, or similar to other sites out there?

Answer (score 1):

[What is the rule for time between an IPO filing and public exchange](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/13266/time-between-ipo-filing-and-public-exchange)

Better than, worse than, or similar to other sites out there?

Answer (score 0):

https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/13404/what-do-you-not-like-about-td-ameritrade

Better than, worse than, or similar to other sites out there?

Comment: This one is asking for opinions, not a great question

Answer (score 0):

[What are the basics of apartment rental finances?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/13323/what-are-the-basics-of-apartment-rental-finances)

Better than, worse than, or similar to other sites out there?

Answer (score 0):

[What is the average cost of a portfolio on a trading site?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/13260/what-is-the-average-cost-of-a-portfolio-on-a-trading-site)

Better than, worse than, or similar to other sites out there?

Answer (score 0):

[What are the fundamental levels that makes a Stock Ideal? (either to sell or buy)](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/13401/what-are-the-fundamental-levels-that-makes-a-stock-ideal-either-to-sell-or-buy)

Better than, worse than, or similar to other sites out there?

Answer (score 0):

[Financing a vehicle a few months before I expect to apply for a mortgage?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/13251/financing-a-vehicle-a-few-months-before-i-expect-to-apply-for-a-mortgage)

Better than, worse than, or similar to other sites out there?

Answer (score 0):

[What is the correct way to report incentive stock options (ISO) on federal taxes?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/13427/what-is-the-correct-way-to-report-incentive-stock-options-iso-on-federal-taxes)

Better than, worse than, or similar to other sites out there?